# plotting a bubble chart with four quadrants on R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, bubble-chart

i have trouble making a 3D bubble plot on R (like is done on excel for instance). Here
is the code i have tried unsuccessfully (the axes are all in percentages and have crazy limits : they go from -10 000% to 10 000%) :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(plot_3D, aes(x = actes_evolution_2020_2021, y = tx_0_nuit_2021)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = regroupement_elsan, size = actes_2021), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07",
                                "#FFB5C5", "#BF87B3", "#7F5AA2")) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12)) + # Réglage de la plage de tailles des points
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-100, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-100, 100))
p
```

Here is the structure of my dataset :

```
structure(list(code_1 = c("M01b", "C01", "C02", "C04", "M01", 
"autres"), regroupement_elsan = c("Endoscopies digestives", "Ortho (+ rhumato et 
rachis)", 
"Chirurgie digestive", "Uro-néphro", "Gastro", "-"), actes_2019 = c(36079, 
29520, 14618, 6515, 9179, 33707), actes_2020 = c(30192, 25451, 
12845, 7376, 7933, 24154), actes_2021 = c(42333, 24055, 13735, 
8196, 6504, 26115), tx_0_nuit_2019 = c(96.0955377574371, 63.5718186783179, 
41.4435389988359, 36.2817362817363, 3.92397302268547, 783.752765264434
), tx_0_nuit_2020 = c(96.0936155567028, 67.3069146785281, 40.5855855855856, 
34.344262295082, 3.29588014981273, 895.206473285694), tx_0_nuit_2021 = 
c(96.7053774299419, 
73.2892690513219, 51.0503369005153, 41.9021364576154, 3.6068530207394, 
849.200890941822), actes_evolution_2019_2020 = c(-16.3169710912165, 
-13.7838753387534, -12.1288822000274, 13.2156561780507, -13.5744634491775, 
-28.3412940932151), actes_evolution_2020_2021 = c(40.2126391096979, 
-5.48504970335154, 6.92876605683145, 11.117136659436, -18.0133619059624, 
8.11873809720957)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "11"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I think package plotly might help but i have failed using it without it keeping only 2 quadrants and not 4 in the plot.
Ideally, i would like my plot to be in 3D. Could anyone help ?

Here is an illustration of what i mean by bubble plot in excel :
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/present-your-data-in-a-bubble-chart-424d7bda-93e8-4983-9b51-c766f3e330d9#:~:text=Create%20Elaborate%20Bubble%20Chart%20in%20Excel%201%20Copy,6%20For%20Minimum%2C%20type%200%20%28zero%29.%20See%20More](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/present-your-data-in-a-bubble-chart-424d7bda-93e8-4983-9b51-c766f3e330d9#:%7E:text=Create%20Elaborate%20Bubble%20Chart%20in%20Excel%201%20Copy,6%20For%20Minimum%2C%20type%200%20%28zero%29.%20See%20More).

Comment: The reason that your scales are wrong is that `scales::percent` is used to convert proportions to percentages. Your values are already on a percentage scale, so this will multiply them by 100. If your change `labels = percent` to `labels = ~ paste0(.x, '%')` you will get the correct labeling.

Comment: R [did add support for gradient fills](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/07/15/new-features-in-the-r-graphics-engine/) somewhat recently, but ggplot doesn't currently support this type of visual decoration. You could potentially create your own custom geom for this but it's important to consider what is really gained by making the points 3D.

Comment: @AllanCameron or ` ~percent(.x, scale=1)` would work as well.

Comment: For the other part of your question, it is not clear what is wrong with your current plot. The pseudo-3D look from Excel is pretty old-fashioned (it looked cool in the late 90s, but now it looks a bit amateurish). It also doesn't add any information. It is possible to do it using a custom grob or gradient fill, but it's not clear why you would go to this effort. If something isn't worth doing, it's not worth doing well.